# CSS Styling Rules

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a CSS rule so that links with be styled with a text of white and a blue background when the user hovers over it. I build a rule that reads like:

```
a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #215b87 !important;
}
```

This works in most cases, but when you have cases like, for example, a Google search, you get HTML like the following:

```
<a aria-label="Page 5" class="fl" href="/search?q=Test+Search&amp;biw=1832&amp;bih=786&amp;ei=QMDRXb-kEoaT1fAPxtGHqAg&amp;start=40&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi_xJTenPLlAhWGSRUIHcboAYU4ChDy0wMIZQ"><span class="csb ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>5</a>
```

Is there a way in the selector that only the text can be selected for applying the formatting only to the text and ignore any span, img tags and the like?

Regards,
George

Answer (score -1):

You can unset all the style rules of children of the anchor tag with a wildcard selector:

```css
a:hover * {
  background-position: unset !important;
  width: auto !important;
  background: unset !important;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #215b87 !important;
}
```

```html
<a aria-label="Page 5" class="fl" href="/search?q=Test+Search&amp;biw=1832&amp;bih=786&amp;ei=QMDRXb-kEoaT1fAPxtGHqAg&amp;start=40&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi_xJTenPLlAhWGSRUIHcboAYU4ChDy0wMIZQ"><span class="csb ch" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>5</a>
```

Comment: When there is inline styling that can't be removed it's acceptable.